# Delete all items from a c++ std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm trying to delete everything from a `std::vector` by using the following code

```
vector.erase( vector.begin(), vector.end() );
```

but it doesn't work.

---

Update: Doesn't clear destruct the elements held by the vector? I don't want that, as I'm still using the objects, I just want to empty the container

Comment: clear() is there. U can use it

Comment: The update doesn't clarify things.

What, exactly, are the vector elements?  Are they pointers or objects?  If they are objects, how are they still in use?  Why do you want to empty the vector?

Comment: 1. What doesn't work? 2. Can it be that you don't know the difference between pointers and pointees? If you store pointers in a vector and then call clear() it will destroy the pointers, not the pointees!

Comment: Your edit seems a bit confused. The vector owns the objects stored in it. If you remove the objects from the vector, then the copies are *destroyed*. That is unavoidable, they have nowhere to live. They're being removed from the place where they were stored. If you don't want that, then you can't meaningfully "empty the container".

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514311/removing-from-stl-stdqueue-without-destructing-the-removed-object

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I think you should use [`std::vector::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
vec.clear();
```

---

EDIT:

> Doesn't clear destruct the elements
>   held by the vector?

Yes it does. It calls the destructor of every element in the vector before returning the memory. That depends on what "elements" you are storing in the vector. In the following example, I am storing the objects them selves inside the vector:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    ~myclass()
    {

    }
...
};

std::vector<myclass> myvector;
...
myvector.clear(); // calling clear will do the following:
// 1) invoke the deconstrutor for every myclass
// 2) size == 0 (the vector contained the actual objects).
```

If you want to share objects between different containers for example, you could store pointers to them. In this case, when `clear` is called, only pointers memory is released, the actual objects are not touched:

```
std::vector<myclass*> myvector;
...
myvector.clear(); // calling clear will do:
// 1) ---------------
// 2) size == 0 (the vector contained "pointers" not the actual objects).
```

For the question in the comment, I think `getVector()` is defined like this:

```
std::vector<myclass> getVector();
```

Maybe you want to return a reference:

```
// vector.getVector().clear() clears m_vector in this case
std::vector<myclass>& getVector();
```

Comment: If your vector contains pointers, this will not release memory but just clear the collection. You have to release memory by yourself.

Comment: @Patrice Sure, but the questioner said nothing about the content of the vector.

Comment: That's why I've added the information. Anyway i agree with your answer.

Comment: It was to do with how I was getting the vector
this->getVector().clear() didnt work
this->m_vector.clear() worked

thanks

Comment: @Michael Maybe getVector() returns a **copy** of m_vector not a reference.

Comment: If the OP's problem had really been with v.erase( v.begin(), v.end() ), merely recommending v.clear() wouldn't help as it's no more than an alias for the former.

Comment: @michael: Can you post the signature of getVector()?

Comment: `clear()` generally will not release memory - it just destructs everything and marks it as unused (but bound to the vector). If you want to truly free memory, try `myvector.swap(std::vector<content_type>());`

Comment: @bdonlan Although the standards say nothing about the new capacity of a vector after a clear operation, I think you made a good point about how implementations deal with it. I'll edit the post to refer to the size instead of the capacity :)

Comment: very good point bdonlan, clear() does not change capacity() if the implementation is somewhat clever, which I espect from an implementation of the standart!

Comment: In the example above, if `myclass` has a vector element like, `std::vector<int> data;`. Then `myclass` has to clear that in the `destructor` by calling `data.clear()`. Like, `~myclass() {data.clear();}`.

Answer (score 33):

`vector.clear()` should work for you. In case you want to shrink the capacity of the `vector` along with clear then

```
std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);
```

Comment: Swap it with itself? .. Doesn't one usually swap it with a new empty vector?

Comment: Yes. After clear the vector will be empty. std::vector<T>(v).swap(v) --is a generic way of shrinking the capacity of the vector.

Comment: This technique is also discussed in one of Herb Sutter's "Guru of the Week" articles:   http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Comment: and now you have shrink_to_fit() , which might be doing same work as this was, under the hood.

Answer (score 10):

vector.clear() is effectively the same as vector.erase( vector.begin(), vector.end() ).

If your problem is about calling `delete` for each *pointer* contained in your vector, try this:

```
#include <algorithm>

template< typename T >
struct delete_pointer_element
{
    void operator()( T element ) const
    {
        delete element;
    }
};

// ...
std::for_each( vector.begin(), vector.end(), delete_pointer_element<int*>() );
```

**Edit:** Code rendered obsolete by C++11 range-for.

Comment: In the erase case, I thought the iterator may become invalid after the first erase. Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: He is not clearing the vector, just deleting the elements. I'd suggest additionally setting the pointer values to null, and then clearing the vector afterwards.

Comment: erase( iterator first, iterator last ); is *defined* to work for spans of elements, which includes the begin()-end() span. I am not 100% sure if v.clear() isn't even officially *defined* in terms of v.erase( v.begin(), v.end() ), but it is definitely at least *functionally* identical.

Comment: Does not compile as of today!  `use of class template requires template arguments`

Comment: @MohammadKanan Should have been  `delete_pointer_element<int*>()`, but has been rendered obsolete by range-for anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Use [v.clear()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/clear/) to empty the vector.

If your vector contains pointers, clear calls the destructor for the object but does not delete the memory referenced by the pointer.

```
vector<SomeClass*> v(0);

v.push_back( new SomeClass("one") );

v.clear();  //Memory leak where "one" instance of SomeClass is lost
```

Answer (score 4):

Is `v.clear()` not working for some reason?

Comment: Doesn't clear destruct the elements held by the vector? I don't want that, as I'm still using the objects, I just want to empty the container

Comment: @michael: My guess is you are storing pointers in your vector and worried about the actual objects being deleted. Is this correct? In that case, clear() will not delete the actual objects, it will just clear the vector only.

Comment: `clear()` does not destroy elements held by the vector. It only clear the collection of objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep pointers in container and don't want to bother with manually destroying of them, then use [boost shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). Here is sample for std::vector, but you can use it for any other STL container (set, map, queue, ...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct foo
{
    foo( const int i_x ) : d_x( i_x )
    {
        std::cout << "foo::foo " << d_x << std::endl;
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo::~foo " << d_x << std::endl;
    }

    int d_x;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr< foo > smart_foo_t;

int main()
{
    std::vector< smart_foo_t > foos;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        smart_foo_t f( new foo( i ) );
        foos.push_back( f );
    }

    foos.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above mentioned benefits of `swap().` That `clear()` does not guarantee deallocation of memory.  You can use `swap()` as follows:

```
std::vector<T>().swap(myvector);
```

Comment: As per the comment below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525535/delete-all-items-from-a-c-stdvector#comment1381495_1525574, clear() then swap() will work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

If your vector look like this `std::vector<MyClass*> vecType_pt` you have to explicitly release memory ,Or if your vector look like : `std::vector<MyClass> vecType_obj` , constructor will be called by vector.Please execute example given below , and understand the difference :

```
  class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            cout<<"MyClass"<<endl;
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            cout<<"~MyClass"<<endl;
        }
    };
    int main() 
    {
        typedef std::vector<MyClass*> vecType_ptr;
        typedef std::vector<MyClass> vecType_obj;
        vecType_ptr myVec_ptr;
        vecType_obj myVec_obj;
        MyClass obj;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            MyClass *ptr=new MyClass();
            myVec_ptr.push_back(ptr);
            myVec_obj.push_back(obj);
        }
        cout<<"\n\n---------------------If pointer stored---------------------"<<endl;
        myVec_ptr.erase (myVec_ptr.begin(),myVec_ptr.end());
        cout<<"\n\n---------------------If object stored---------------------"<<endl;
        myVec_obj.erase (myVec_obj.begin(),myVec_obj.end());
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Class;
std::vector<Class*> vec = some_data;

for (unsigned int i=vec.size(); i>0;) {
    --i;
    delete vec[i];
    vec.pop_back();
}
// Free memory, efficient for large sized vector
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

Performance: theta(n)

If pure objects (not recommended for large data types, then just
    vec.clear();