# Remove all elements in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete all items from a c++ std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525535/delete-all-items-from-a-c-stdvector)

I think using begin in an iterator is messing this up since it's only iterating 26 times and skipping every 2 elements. How else can I do it?

```
void clearVector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        vector.erase(vector.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you didn't find out about `clear` on your own, reading the documentation for `erase` would have been a start. -1.

Comment: @jogojapan: That question isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MarceloCantos The OP wants to remove _all_ elements from a vector, suggests a method that doesn't work and asks "how else can I do it". How is this not equivalent to asking "how to delete all items from a vector"?

Comment: @jogojapan: Having equivalent titles doesn't make the questions identical. The other question exhibits a different type of misunderstanding, and has an additional aspect — wanting to retain the objects after removal. Those factors warrant a different response to what this question needs.

Comment: @MarceloCantos The other question was originally about how to delete all items, and was later updated to include "retaining the objects". The answers it received cover _both_ aspects. Everything the question above is about is fully addressed by that other question.

Comment: @MarceloCantos - Both questions are ultimately asking the same thing, and both have the same answer. They're duplicates. That the details of the two questions differ slightly doesn't mean they aren't duplicates. It just means that both questions have a bit of the XY problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ).

Comment: First this will not erase the first 52 elements. Think about it. You erase the first one (zero-th element), then increment `i`, but element 1 has now become element 0, so on iteration `myVector.begin() + 1` (remember `i` now equals 1) now references what was the 3rd element to begin with.  Better to call `myVector.clear()`.  Second, if you insist doing it yourself: `while (myVector.size()) { myVector.erase(myVector.begin()); }`

Answer (score 24):

You call the [`std::vector::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) method:

```
myVector.clear();
```

where I have changed the instance name from `vector` to `myVector`. It is not a good idea to use the name of a class for an instance.

Answer (score 12):

`std::vector` has a `clear` member, you know:

```
void clearVector() {
    vector.clear();
}
```

Anyway, since you're erasing from the left the size will be shrinking also. This works the way you intend, although it is inefficient because it will have to do O(N) copies towards the front each iteration.

```
void clearVector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        vector.erase(vector.begin());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use std::vector::clear() to clear elements or swap with an empty container is much faster.

```
vec.clear();
```

or

```
std::vector<DataType>().swap(vec);
```

*Note: your variable `vector` is not good variable name, better change it to something else.*

Comment: In C++11, `std::vector` has a method [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) that makes the "swap-with-copy" (or "swap-with-empty") trick obsolete. You can now write `vec.clear(); vec.shrink_to_fit();` to erase all elements of the vector and decrease its capacity as well.

Comment: The "swap-with-copy" (or "swap-with-empty") trick isn't obsolete. It depends on the implementation whether `shrink_to_fit` decreases the capacity. Most implementations do it. But some may not.

Answer (score 2):

```
      vec.erase(vec.begin() /* first you want delete */, 
                vec.begin() + vec.size() /* 1 beyond the last you want to delete */);
      // or if you have to erase all elements:
      vec.clear();
```

so you don't need to iterate.

Comment: just to stress it deletes a range, if last = vec.end(), better to use directly vec.clear(). I've just chosen a "special" range, i.e. all the elements, maybe I should write just N instead