# Deletion of elements from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I want to delete all the elements from the std::vector

```
    for (Entity * cb : cbs)
    {
        delete cb;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all items from a c++ std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525535/delete-all-items-from-a-c-stdvector)

Comment: This method is ok, but I would recommend emptying the vector afterwards by calling `cbs.clear()`.

Comment: Just for clarity, since you didn't specify: you're asking about a vector of raw pointers to objects which should be deleted, right? Not just emptying the vector itself?

Comment: @Useless Yes, it is just vector of pointers. I would say it not just about deletion. It could be any operation on elements but same for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

[std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) would be the alternative to an explicit loop:

```
std::for_each(cbs.begin(), cbs.end(), [](Entity *cb){
    delete cb;
});
```

Comment: I just have to ask why you would encourage the OP to ask these kinds of questions by answering them, when there are obviously numerous dupe targets to questions such as this one? It took med 5 seconds to find a dupe target.

Comment: I don't think clearing vector would delete pointers.

Comment: This has a different purpose to calling delete on each element. I think you might be implying that the op should forgo pointers or use smart pointers in their vector. But I doubt the op will know that since they're asking the question.

Comment: @dfrib Op is a relatively new user and site encourages us to be friendly.  Site doesn't award any reputation for closing an issue as a duplicate.  If that is the desired behavior they should award reputation for it.

Comment: I am kind of unsure, but can there be a one liner lamda function for this problem. I mean performing same operation on all elements, there must be better way to it rather than looping.

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena If you have to call `delete` for each element there's no way to avoid a loop. You could use a standard library algorithm but the loop is still in there.

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena question changed to something different.  for loop is fine, you can also use std::for_each and pass in a functor that does the delete.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Can you point be to such library algorithms.

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks. std::for_each is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: Why would you use `for_each` instead of a simple ranged for loop? It makes the code less idiomatic and more complicated for no benefit.

Comment: @interjay I don't there is anything wrong with using a for-loop.  for_each is a standard algorithm, so it's just as idiomatic (maybe even more so in that it's C++ opposed to C).  for_each has an version with an execution policy argument to easily parallelizing it.

Comment: `for_each` was in the standard before range-based for was added in 2011. The reason range-based for was added is that it's clearer and easier to use. Yes, there are specific cases where `for_each` might still be useful but they are very rare and this certainly isn't one of them. Also, your claim that range-based for exists in C is incorrect.

Comment: @interjay obviously, I mean, the for-loops in general.  Thanks for the sharing the historical context, and your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Use shared or unique pointers. This results in the automatic deletion when clearing the vector (or in the destructor of the vector in case you don't clear it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
private:
    size_t m_index;
public:
    Test(size_t index)
        : m_index(index)
    {
    }

    void PrintIndex()
    {
        std::cout << m_index << std::endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor invoked for " << m_index << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>> v;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back(new Test(i));
    }

    for (auto& t : v)
    {
        t->PrintIndex();
    }

    //v.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

As for executing other arbitrary operations on every element as mentioned in the comment:

There are other ways to achieve the this result, but there's nothing nothing that's better than the ranged for loop imho; it's just 3 simple lines (plus loop body) after all.

Answer (score 1):

You clarified in the comments you have a vector of raw pointers and want to delete all objects pointed by them.

So how do you do it?

**You don't!**

In C++ we don't do manual memory management (raw `new`/`delete`). It's buggy (any exception will make you leak memory), error prone and confusing (who is supposed to delete the objects). Instead we use RAII. For this we have smart pointers. So use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and everything is correctly managed for you.

> It could be any operation on elements but same for all elements.

A range for loop like yours is the idiomatic way to do it:

```
for (auto&& elem : vector)
{
    foo(elem);
}
```